# Gitlab CI: terraform apply job fails with exit code 141 after everything ran successfully

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, aws-iot

Im using gitlab ci jobs to automate my aws iot setup upon updating a branch.

my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init

stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan
  dependencies:
    - validate

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - yes yes | terraform apply
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
```

in the terraform apply job, everything runs successfully but the job still exits with Error Code 141.
These are the last lines of the terraform apply debug:

```
 local_file.water_switchCert: Creation complete after 0s [id=1085d628417927a07dac038743969c1127b4fd0d]
 local_file.sensor_2_key: Creation complete after 0s [id=d9952a9eb0d990b5c6e34fda74a29785c62dcd56]
 local_file.water_switchKey: Creation complete after 0s [id=b05acd1ef2aa31b8493ee30a461164aa3ddd55ca]
 Apply complete! Resources: 8 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
Running after_script
00:01
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 141
```

I really dont know why this behaviour occurs. Maybe someone experienced the same issue and can help, it would be appreciated

Comment: Try with detailed terraform logging that'll give you clue what's going on. To enable logging, set TF_LOG to DEBUG (or TRACE). Look at Debugging Terraform at https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html for full details. BTW, on a side note, it'll be better to use _**terraform -auto-approve apply**_ within your gitlab ci job avoiding prompts altogether.

Comment: @Avnish using the -auto-approve option instead of the yes command did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Gitlab CI omnibus where I wanted to login to my private npm registry. I used `yes '' | npm login` command. it successfully logged in but pipeline failed with **error code 141**. changing code to `(yes '' || true) | npm login` worked for me. the problem arrises because yes command produces more yes string than what **terraform apply** realy needs. so stdin is manipulated by yes command. pipe it with true, ensures you that just necessary 'yes' inputs come into stdin. so rewire script as:

`(yes yes || true) | terraform apply`